# Subconsulta con datos de la misma tabla en sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy utilizando SQL SERVER 2012

Deseo hacer una subconsulta con datos de la misma tabla que tiene la consulta relacionando tres campos, me explico , la consulta es

```
SELECT m.COMPROBANT, COUNT (m.COMPROBANT)Item_ENTRADA, m.FECHA_TRS,m.COD_PROVEE,m.COD_AREA,
SUM(m.ENTRADAS) Total_ENTRADA
  FROM MOVIM AS m
WHERE m.COMPROBANT  LIKE '1%'
GROUP BY m.COMPROBANT,m.FECHA_TRS,m.COD_PROVEE,m.COD_AREA
```

Y para los datos de la subconsulta los campos

```
m.COMPROBANT, COUNT (m.COMPROBANT)Item_SALIDAS, m.FECHA_TRS,m.COD_PROVEE,m.COD_AREA,SUM(m.ENTRADAS) Total_SALIDAS
```

debe ser iguales a los de la consulta pero el WHERE de las subconsulta debe tener

```
m.COMPROBANT  LIKE '2%'
```

resutado como se refle en la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la tabla MOVIM hay un campo que se llama COMPROBANT pero en este hay datos que empiezan con '1' y datos que empiezan con '2' entonces lo que deseo es que una columna todos lo que empiecen con '1' y otra columna los que empiecen con '2' por eso razón pongo LIKE pero solo me sale en una sola columna, tanto lo que empiezan con '1' como los que empiezan con '2'

muchas gracias por su ayuda de antemano

Comment: realmente no te explicas bien y la imgen no me carga, por que si todos los datos deben ser [LIKE '2%'] entonces por que nos los pones en el where ?

Comment: Y.. ¿Que relaciona ambas consultas?

Comment: en la  tabla MOVIM  hay un campo que se llama COMPROBANT pero este compos hay datos que empiecen con '1' y datos que empiecen con '2' entonce lo que deseo que una columna todos lo que empiecen con '1' y otra columna que empiece con '2' por eso razón pongo LIKE pero solo me sale en una columna  todo tanto lo que empiezan con '1' como los que empiezan con '2' espero haberme explicado

Comment: del dato COMPROBANT necesitas ver la SALIDA y ENTRADA?

eso es?

Answer (score 1):

Primero que nada, este es un problema que debería ser resuelto en la capa de visualización y no en la de datos, tiene poco sentido ya que justamente no hay una lógica que relacione las dos conjuntos de datos, la lógica es netamente de presentación. Sin embargo, si el escenario te obliga a hacerlo desde la capa de datos, lo que podrías hacer es generar un `id` entre las dos consultas para poder relacionarlas de manera arbitraria. Lo vamos a hacer numerando cada fila, de forma tal, que luego haciendo un `FULL OUTER JOIN` iremos "juntando" la fila 1 de la consulta 1 con la fila 1 de la consulta 2, así hasta completar los datos de ambas consultas. Si hubiera más filas de un lado que de otro, el `FULL OUTER` nos permitirá mostrar ambas sin perder información:

```
SELECT  T2.COMPROBANT,
        T2.Item_SALIDA,
        T1.COMPROBANT,
        T1.Item_ENTRADA
        FROM (SELECT    COMPROBANT, 
                        COUNT (COMPROBANT) Item_ENTRADA,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COMPROBANT) NR
                        FROM MOVIM
                        WHERE LEFT(COMPROBANT,1) = '1'
                        GROUP BY COMPROBANT
            ) T1
        FULL OUTER JOIN ( SELECT    COMPROBANT, 
                                    COUNT (COMPROBANT) Item_SALIDA,
                                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COMPROBANT) NR
                                    FROM MOVIM
                                    WHERE LEFT(COMPROBANT,1) = '2'
                                    GROUP BY COMPROBANT
            ) T2
            ON T1.NR = T2.NR
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio por tu ayuda me sirvio full

Answer (score 0):

No se entiende muy bien lo que necesitas o lo que tienes, lo que yo entiendo es lo siguiente( *corrígeme si me equivoco*):
Lo que necesitas no es un subconsulta, necesitas 2 consultas:
   1- Una que te recoja los datos de entra en las que la condición es `LIKE '1%'`
   2- Otra que recoja los datos de salida en la que la condición es `LIKE '2%'`
   3- Y estas dos consultas juntarlas de forma horizontal en una sola tabla

```
SELECT 
    COMPROBANT, 
    COUNT (COMPROBANT)item, 
    FECHA_TRS,
    COD_PROVEE,
    COD_AREA,
    SUM(ENTRADAS) total,
    entrada AS movimiento
  FROM MOVIM 
WHERE COMPROBANT  LIKE '1%'
GROUP BY COMPROBANT,FECHA_TRS,COD_PROVEE,COD_AREA

UNION 

SELECT 
    COMPROBANT, 
    COUNT (COMPROBANT)item,
    FECHA_TRS,
    COD_PROVEE,
    COD_AREA,
    SUM(ENTRADAS) total,
    salida AS movimiento
WHERE COMPROBANT  LIKE '2%'
GROUP BY COMPROBANT,FECHA_TRS,COD_PROVEE,COD_AREA
```

Esta query te devolverá todos los datos que necesitas lo único que estarán estructurados de otra forma, con la columna `movimiento` puedes controlar cada linea de datos si de es de entrada o de salida y cada una de ellas tendrá su propio `WHERE`

Mi recomendación es la siguiente:

- Si realmente necesitas estructurarlos de la forma que planteabas porque es una consulta para una vista o algo que se detenga en la query utilizar el metodo [PIVOT](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017) con esto pudes darle exactamente esta estructura ( No tengo todos los datos por lo tanto no te lo puedo aplicar a la query de arriba)

- Si vas a usar estos datos con algún código aparte del sql, evitar usar el pivot y procesar los datos de la query que te he puesto en la aplicación misma, con una baja cantidad de datos no notaras mucha diferencia. Utilizo una consulta parecida en mi caso y después de unas pruebas hace un par de días he quitado el PIVOT de mi consulta, en mi caso trato con mas de 1,2 millones de lineas de datos, en mi caso me renta mas volver a tratar los datos en el programa que recibirlos estructurados. Dependiendo de cuantas lineas solicite puede marca muchos segundos de diferencia de espera.

*(Lo mencionado anteriormente, si esto no es lo que pedías, actualiza la pregunta, pon en ejemplo de las tablas que tienes, del formato de datos y del resultado total que quieres obtener)*

Answer (score 0):

intenta con esto!. Si no es lo que buscas es necesario enviar una foto  haciendo un select a tu tabla `MOVIM` y solo haciendo un filtro por  `WHERE COMPROBANT LIKE '1%' OR COMPROBANT LIKE '2%'` para ver como se puede trabajar la data, suerte!

```
SELECT x.FECHA_TRS,x.COD_PROVEE,x.COD_AREA
,x.Item_ENTRADA,x.Total_ENTRADA
,y.Item_SALIDA,y.Total_SALIDA
FROM (
SELECT 
    COUNT (m.COMPROBANT)Item_ENTRADA
    ,m.FECHA_TRS
    ,m.COD_PROVEE
    ,m.COD_AREA
    ,SUM(m.ENTRADAS) Total_ENTRADA
    FROM MOVIM AS m
    WHERE m.COMPROBANT  LIKE '1%'
    GROUP BY m.FECHA_TRS,m.COD_PROVEE,m.COD_AREA) AS x 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
    COUNT (m.COMPROBANT)Item_SALIDA
    ,m.FECHA_TRS
    ,m.COD_PROVEE
    ,m.COD_AREA
    ,SUM(m.ENTRADAS) Total_SALIDA
    FROM MOVIM AS m
    WHERE m.COMPROBANT  LIKE '2%'
    GROUP BY m.FECHA_TRS,m.COD_PROVEE,m.COD_AREA) AS y
ON x.FECHA_TRS=y.FECHA_TRS AND x.COD_PROVEE=y.COD_PROVEE AND x.COD_AREA=y.COD_AREA
```

Comment: bro me sale bien pero tengo un problema como hay mas datos que comiencen con 1 que comiencen con 2 en la tabla MOVIM los datos que comienzan con dos se me repiten varias veces